# Botones dinamicos con eventos en java

Tags: java, botón, eventos

Estoy creando botones de forma dinámica, y les asigno un actionListener, el detalle es que no se como saber que botón esta presionando de todos los que he creado.

Aquí creo los botones con un while

```
      while (rs.next()) {
            JButton BImagen;
            name = rs.getString(1);
            BImagen = new JButton(name);
            BImagen.addActionListener(ALCategorias);
            panels[i].add(BImagen);
```

Y este es el ActionListener:

```
ActionListener ALCategorias = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("El boton tiene un ActionListener");
    }
};
```

Como hacer una acción u otra dependiendo de que botón presioné

Answer (score 0):

[El Javadoc de ActionEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html).

En concreto, te explica que como hereda de [java.util.EventObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html), tiene un método [getSource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource())

*getSource()* te devuelve el objeto de origen del evento, en este caso el botón.

Así que dentro del listener, puedes hacer

```
JButton boton = (JButton) e.getSource();
System.out.println(e.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           String id_boton = e.getActionCommand();
                                    
        }
    });
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y agregar una explicación de por que ese fragmento de código soluciona el problema por favor? Así aumentarás su calidad, será mejor recibida y tanto el autor de la pregunta como quienes vean tu respuesta más adelante podrían aprender algo nuevo.